# Как запустить функцию 1 раз

Tags: javascript

Есть функция прослушки DOM на изменение

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) {
        if (event.target.className == "ymaps-2-1-72-balloon__content") {
            imp();
        }
    });
});
```

В итоге DOMSubtreeModified находит изменение в 3х одинаковых классах и запускает функцию imp() 3 раза. А мне нужно запустить только 1 раз.

Пробовал event.target.className[0] не помогает.

Может return в нужном месте прекратить работу DOMSubtreeModified или есть какая служебная функция для остановки.

Comment: попробуй `one()` вместо `on()`

Comment: у меня происходит сотни изменений в #map, поэтому и делаю проверку на поиск нужных мне изменений. поэтому one() отключает прослушку после первого изменения.

Comment: [This event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) has been deprecated in favor of the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как сказали в комментариях, это событие – deprecated.

Решить проблему можно просто

```
let listener = function(event) {
        if (event.target.className == "ymaps-2-1-72-balloon__content") {
            imp();
            map.off('DOMSubtreeModified.EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE')
        }
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    const map = $('#map')
    map.on('DOMSubtreeModified.EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE',listener);  
});
```

при необходимости заново навесить слушатель - вызываем в нужном месте опять конструкцию

`map.on('DOMSubtreeModified.EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE',listener);`

следует учитывать, что такое отключение событий отключит все слушатели *DOMSubtreeModified*, подписанные на  namespace `DOMSubtreeModified.EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE`

неплохая статья - https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/

Comment: Да, пример рабочий. А как запустить обратно слежение из другой функции? просто  map.on('DOMSubtreeModified.EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE') не помогает, хотя переменную сделал глобальной. нужно весь этот код обернуть в функциe и её уже запускать, поможете с кодом?

Comment: @КонстантинСоколов, вынеси  callback в  именованную  функцию например callbackFunction  и  подключай его снова через $('#map').on('DOMSubtreeModified.EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE', calbackFunction)

Comment: мои знания ненастолько сильны. чтобы такое написать :(

Comment: @КонстантинСоколов , адаптировал.. теперь понтянее?

Comment: спасибище. работает. только я const убрал, чтобы переменная стала глобальной. оставил просто map = $('#map')

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, обработчик открытого балуна делается просто (умные люди подсказали).

```
myMap.balloon.open(coords, {
    //здесь доработать код вывода формы ввода
    contentBody: '<div id="forma"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Сохранить</button></div>'
}).then(myfunc)
```